# File Maker Pro 12: Possible to flag/remove matched fields from separate table?

Tags: database, filemaker, mailing-list

*Hi all. My first question here (after much googling/searching).*

I am working on migrating a plethora of mailing list spreadsheets to a simple database, using File Maker. One stumbling block is - I need to be able to flag records as inactive, based on if their address exists in a separate table.

ie. To keep it simple:

- **table1** has name, address, and zip.
- **table2** has address and zip.
- If an address/zip combination in **table1** exists also in **table2**, then it needs to be flagged in **table1** as inactive.

*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: Could you show de tables schema? I mean what's the PK of each table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would create a calculated field called something like addressZIP that combines address and ZIP into a single string.

Then, in table 1, create a calculated field.

Enter this

If (IsEmpty ( FilterValues ( List ( table2::addressZIP ) ; addressZIP )),"","FLAG").

I think that will work, but I'm not positive. I'm not at a computer with FM right now so I can't test it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Eric. Right now, Count is triggering _an expression was found where a field alone is needed_ but I do understand what you were trying to do, and agree your suggestion is the right path to go down. I'll post again if I can figure it out.

Comment: Update: still not able to get it working. Any additional help appreciated.

Comment: Sorry it's been so long. Try Replacing with Count()=0 with IsEmpty().

Comment: Thanks @Eric. That worked. I'm new here, so not sure on the protocol, but I'm going to edit your answer to reflect the updated code. Hopefully, it still gives you the proper credit. If not, feel free to re-edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a subquery to get the table1 ids and make an update with the IN clause. That can be done with UPDATE FROM too but I think this approach is more understandable. You can begin doing the subquery to check it and later include in the update.

```
UPDATE
    table1
SET
    flaged = 1
WHERE
    id IN(
          SELECT
            t1.id
          FROM
            table1 t1, table2 t2
          WHERE
            t1.address = t2.address AND t1.zip = t2.zip
    )
```